# How to store index in ELKI?

Tags: indexing, store, dbscan, elki

I am using ELKI 0.7.2 (master) for running DBSCAN with R* tree on a large data set. Afterwards, I need to store the tree persistently, so that it can be reloaded in memory when new data points are evaluated whether they are noise or not. To this end, I tried PersistentPageFileFactory and got the following error

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: de.lmu.ifi.dbs.elki.index.tree.spatial.rstarvariants.rstar.RStarTreeNode cannot be cast to de.lmu.ifi.dbs.elki.persistent.ExternalizablePage
```

Although I simply revised RStarTreeNode to implement the interface ExternalizablePage, it didn't help. When I utilzed OnDiskArrayPageFileFactory, I got another error as follows

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: IOException occurred during reading of page 0
at de.lmu.ifi.dbs.elki.persistent.OnDiskArrayPageFile.readPage(OnDiskArrayPageFile.java:113)
```

Is there a way to store an index, e.g. R* tree, into a file and to load it from the file?

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The disk deserialization code has been unused for years, and thus is likely broken.

I am even not sure if it ever fully supported reading back the index from disk standalone; I assume it was only implemented to simulate an on-disk index for benchmarking purposes (i.e., it will read and write the data from disk, but it probably cannot read an existing index).

This just is not a functionaly I needed, so I never worked on this code much beyond refactoring. And I have actually been trying to slowly remove much of this code (in particular `ExternalizablePage`) because I did not have the impression it is usable.

I have a rewritten version of the R-tree somewhere that is better suited for actual on-disk usage. But it is not finished, it does not support R*-tree re-insertions yet. So the code is not published yet (and may never get finished, unfortunately).

So you may need to rewrite large parts of that code to make it usable.

If you do so, please share your modifications on Github.

Comment: Hi Erich, thanks a lot for your answer. It is a pity that on-disk usage is not supported. Hopefully it will be token into account in future release, since in some case the index is desired to store persistently (representing "golden" data sets) so that it can be reused in any time to deetect oulier candidates..

Comment: It may, or may not work. I don't really know, because I don't use it. Bulk-loading an R-tree is for me is usually fast enough, and maybe even faster than actually reading an existing index from disk.
Open-source projects rely on *your* contributions. If you need certain functionality that is missing, please contribute it, rather than hoping someone else will eventually do this.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to ask the same question. My case is the same. It is not necessary to store clusters if a dataset is 10k or 100K,
but if you want to get clusters for 1M dataset or more it takes more than 1 hour. I found little workaround how to store model on disk.
To detect outliers you have to get KnnQuery from dataset where is no noises. It takes less time than clusters counting (1-3 minutes for 1M dataset). 
So you can count clusters and store only elements which belong to clusters and use it.

First, calculate clusters as described here. https://elki-project.github.io/howto/java_api 
Process the result (persist only points that are not noise):

```
    List<String> clusterPoints = new ArrayList<>(); // List which will be stored in file

    for (Cluster<Model> cluster : clusters.getAllClusters()) {
        if (!cluster.isNoise()) { // write to output only not noises

            for (DBIDIter iterator = cluster.getIDs().iter(); iterator.valid(); iterator.advance()) {
                NumberVector vector = relation.get(iterator);

                for (int i = 0; i < vector.toArray().length; i++) {
                    clusterPoints.add(String.valueOf(vector.toArray()[i]));
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Save this clusterPoints in the file. To restore clusters get relation from points from the file as described https://elki-project.github.io/howto/java_api#creating-a-database

```
    double[] pointToDetect = YOUR_POINT_TO_DETECT_OUTLIER;
    // get db as described here: https://elki-project.github.io/howto/java_api#creating-a-database
    Relation<NumberVector> relation = db.getRelation(TypeUtil.NUMBER_VECTOR_FIELD);
    NumberVector vector = DoubleVector.FACTORY.newNumberVector(pointToDetect);

    KNNQuery<NumberVector> knnQuery = QueryUtil.getKNNQuery(relation, EuclideanDistanceFunction.STATIC); // or any other DistanceFunction
    KNNList list = model.getKnnQuery().getKNNForObject(vector, NEAREST_NEIGHBORS_NUMBER);

    DoubleDBIDPair pairNearest = list.get(0);
    double distanceNearest = pairNearest.doubleValue();
    if (distanceNearest > EPSILON) {
        log.warn("Outlier detected!");
    }
```

It works fine, but I`m found that on some data clusters restoring takes too long time. 
        That's why cluster storing implementation is still needed.